# Improve rendering speed of video thumbnail in flutter

Tags: flutter

So i have a video which i use Video Player to show the thumbnail like so:

```
    class VideoPlayerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  VideoPlayerWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.path,
    required this.sourceType,
    this.height,
    this.width,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String path;
  final SourceType sourceType;
  final double? height;
  final double? width;

  @override
  State<VideoPlayerWidget> createState() => _VideoPlayerWidgetState();
}

class _VideoPlayerWidgetState extends State<VideoPlayerWidget> {
  late VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
  // ChewieController? _chewieController;
  // bool _videoPlayerControllerHasError = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    switch (widget.sourceType) {
      case SourceType.asset:
        _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.asset(widget.path);
        break;
      case SourceType.network:
        _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.path);
        break;
      case SourceType.file:
        _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(File(widget.path));
        break;
      case SourceType.contentUri:
        _videoPlayerController =
            VideoPlayerController.contentUri(Uri.parse(widget.path));
        break;
    }

    _videoPlayerController.initialize().then((value) => setState((){}));

        // .then((value) => setState(() {
        //
        // }));

    // _videoPlayerController.addListener(() {
    //   if (_videoPlayerController.value.hasError){
    //     _videoPlayerControllerHasError = true;
    //   }
    // });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoPlayerController.dispose();
    // _chewieController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if ( !_videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized) {
      return Skeleton(
        height: widget.height ?? 0,
        width: widget.width ?? 0,
      );
    }
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        ChewiePlayingScreen(videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,).launch(context);
      },
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: widget.height,
            width: widget.width,
            child: _videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized
                ? VideoPlayer(_videoPlayerController)
                : Offstage(),
          ),
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Icon(
                Icons.play_circle_outline,
                color: SVAppWhite,
                size: 35,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChewiePlayingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChewiePlayingScreen({Key? key, required this.videoPlayerController}) : super(key: key);

  final VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;

  @override
  State<ChewiePlayingScreen> createState() => _ChewiePlayingScreenState();
}

class _ChewiePlayingScreenState extends State<ChewiePlayingScreen> {
  late ChewieController chewieController;


  @override
  void initState() {
    chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: widget.videoPlayerController,
      aspectRatio: widget.videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: widget.videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
        child: Chewie(
          controller: chewieController,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


}
```

as you can see all i have done is the standard thing, assign a video controller and initialize it, yes it does show the thumbnail but its very slow, it takes up to 20 seconds just for a video of 3mb.

I am getting the file from ImagePicker and the files are from local storage.

Ps : the videos recorded from the camera seem to work just fine.

Comment: Is it taking 20 sec even for a single instance of the class? Assuming you are generating a list of thumbnails and for each item you are creating and instance of the video player. If yes, you might need to think otherwise as this could be performance sensitive. So, if it's an asset video, keep a thumbnail in asset. If it's a network video, generating the thumbnail in your server maybe a better option.

Comment: @NiladriRaychaudhuri it's a file that the user chooses from local storage, anyways i used VideoCompress package to generate the thumbnails and its far faster than video players, i also noticed that the imagePicker package copies the videos or image i pick from the local storage to the cache of the app and as you can imagine that gets slow depending on the file size, do you know of any package that gives me a direct refernce to the file path, instead of copying.